# Text based adventure game using GUI having issues with being able to continue from pressing buttons

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm trying to make a Text Based Adventure Game in Java using GUI for a summative project, the issue I am having is when I press option A, it will work once, and doesn't work afterwards. I haven't gotten any Option B stuff added since it wont do any good if I don't have a way to make it work in the first place.
    import java.awt.*;

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;


public class Project extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

private static final int WIDTH = 840;

private static final int HEIGHT = 480;



private JLabel gameText;

private JButton optionA, optionB, exitB;



private ExitButtonHandler ebHandler;



 public project()

 {

    gameText = new JLabel("<HTML><br>You wake up in a forest, there is a path which
 heads north. There also seems to be a old trail that leads deeper in the woods.</br>
 </html>");         


    optionA = new JButton("Head North");
    optionA.setActionCommand("optionA");
    optionA.addActionListener(this);
    optionB = new JButton("Go deeper into the forest.");
    optionB.setActionCommand("optionB");
    optionB.addActionListener(this);
    exitB = new JButton("Exit");

    ebHandler = new ExitButtonHandler();

    exitB.addActionListener(ebHandler);


    setTitle("Adventuregame");

    Container pane = getContentPane();

    pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 2));




    pane.add(gameText);

    pane.add(optionA);

    pane.add(optionB);

    pane.add(exitB);



    setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    setVisible(true);

    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{

    if(e.getActionCommand().equals("optionA") )
    {
       gameText.setText("<HTML><br>You find yourself on the pathway to a major capital 
city, the walls of the kingdom head towards the sky and the gate is wide open, you can 
hear the sounds of busy life from inside the castle gates. As you head in, a guard 
confronts       
you and asks why you are there.</br></HTML>");
                   optionA.setText("I'm lost and trying to find my way.");
            optionB.setText("Ignore the guard");
             optionA.setActionCommand("optionA2");
             optionA.addActionListener(this);
             if(e.getActionCommand().equals("optionA2"))
    {
       gameText.setText("<HTML><br>The guard checks you for weapons, finding nothing he   
takes you to the tavern to find someone who may be able to help you out. In the Tavern     
there are some drunkards singing in the corner and a band of mercenaries on your right.
At the bar there is a older man whom you seem to reconise</br></HTML>");
                   optionA.setText("Go towards the Mercenaries.");
            optionB.setText("Go to the Older Man.");
             optionA.setActionCommand("optionA3");
             optionA.addActionListener(this);$
```

I'm trying to get it so that each time I press the button it will update to the next 
section, currently I have been unable to find anything on how to do this.

Comment: btw your constructor has to be like class name with uppercase, the problem is that you are registering twice the sameActionListener to the button itself, what do you want to do i didnt understand

Comment: Pretty much what I'm trying to do is so when you press optionA, it will do the first if statement, then there will be A or B, if you press A again it goes to the next, so it branches out. I hope thath elps clarify? and for the class name I changed the name of it on here as it involved my name on the actual version as it's a summative. Also is there a way to change it from optionA to a new one so I can have it work in my code like that? Or no?

Comment: A single blank line of white space in source code is *always* enough.

Answer (score 1):

You're setting both of your action commands in the same class... Well, the action commands will have different commands depending on context, right? Then, you need to have different listeners for these situations. Creating an object in the class is (in my humble opinion) verbose and heap-consuming. You could try this:

```
    public class Project {
       //do your stuff for the class here and, in the constructor...
       public Project(){
         this.optionA = new JButton("First option.");
         this.optionB = new JButton("Second option.");
         this.optionA.setActionListener(new ActionListener(){
             // enter the code for the optionA listener.
         });
         this.optionB.setActionListener(new ActionListener(){
             // enter the code for the optionB listener.
         });
       }
    }
```

If you ever feel like changing it, just reset the action listener whenever you need to do so.

As nachokk said it, rewrite your constructor to pair with the class name, otherwise you'll get an error.

Another thing... it would be nice to split this game in different objects, to maintain their private state and make extensions and maintenance easy.

Comment: Thanks both of you, I've been messing around with what you guys said but now I'm just confused on the one thing. I had the action command if statements. Is that a good way to do it, or would it be easier to replace those with something better? Because I'm unsure of the actioncommand if statements and how it fully works. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Well, I believe having things well written with certain is better. I have little knowledge of the action command either, but setting the action listener seems more certain that that element WILL execute that certain block of code, without depending of an if statement.

Comment: The issue is when I get it to execute, it either skips to the last option, or doesn't change at all. I can't seem to get it to go step by step

Comment: That is why you should use objects instead. You could have one to manage the sequences in a linear form. I could help you with this, if you want.